# Setting my value to usestate after clicking second time first gets assigned there

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is so that I get a problem like doing that when I write email for the first time and it is sent in the database. Then I expect something to come back. Which also do. But it adds nothing to my usestate at all. But when I try to click again and write email again. Then the message I expected is added to my usestate.

So after the second time I have clicked it works exactly as it should and I want them to but it does nothing the first time.

Here you can see my html part for the react.tsx file.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => submitClick(e)}>
    <label className='labelValue'>Email</label>
      <input
      type="text"
      className='w-full border-2 border-slate-100 p-2 md:rounded-lg mt-1 md:mt-2'
      value={email}
      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      placeholder='Email here' />
    <button disabled={disabledNow} className='btn w-full'>
       {disabledNow ? "Account are createde now." : "Create user"}
    </button>
</form>
```

Here can u see my React for at post to database in my react.tsx file.

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [dataValue, setDataValue] = useState([]);
const [item, setItem] = useState(0);
const [disabledNow, setDisabledNow] = useState(false);

const submitClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setItem(1);
  setDisabledNow(true)
}

useEffect(() => {
  const dataMail = {
    Email: email
  };

  let ignore = false;
  if (item === 1) {
    if (!ignore) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios.post("https://localhost:7176/api/user", dataMail)
        const fetchItem = await result.data;
        setDataValue(fetchItem);//not adding fetchItem first time i make a click onSubmit. But after this i get a fetchItem to setDataValue.
        console.log(dataValue);
      }

      fetchData();

      setEmail('');
      setItem(0)
      ignore = true

      if (dataValue.length > 0) {
        console.log("Out of Fetch now. HERE")
        toast(dataValue[1], { duration: 7000 })
        console.log("Notify now HERE")
      }
    }
  }

}, [dataValue, email, item])
```

As I said, I have also tried to remove async and await and it still gives the same problem that I don't have it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chained promised instead of `async await` in `useEffect`. Also refer to comments in code for better understanding.

```
// create ignore as global variable.
let ignore = false;

useEffect(() => {
    const dataMail = {
      Email: email
    };
  
    if (item === 1) {
      if (!ignore) {
          axios.post("https://localhost:7176/api/user", dataMail)
          .then((response) => {
            const fetchItem =  response.data;
            setDataValue(fetchItem);
            // new data won't be available here, so you need to use fetchItem
            console.log(fetchItem);
            setEmail('');
            setItem(0)
            ignore = true
            if (fetchItem.length > 0) {
              console.log("Out of Fetch now. HERE")
              toast(fetchItem[1], { duration: 7000 })
              console.log("Notify now HERE")
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    }
  
  }, [dataValue, email, item])
```

Comment: It still gives the same problem even though it has been done that way. But at the same time it also tells. "Assignments to the ignore variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after render"

Comment: @J.Petersen the error says, `ignore` var will lose it value after render. You need to use `useRef` or `useMemo` for ignore var.

Comment: @J.Petersen try `setDataValue([...fetchItem]);` in `useEffect`

Comment: After the last message: give this me a error: "fetchItem is not iterable", i will try to make a useRef later tomorrow.

Comment: @J.Petersen you can adjust response.data to match your API response

Comment: Well, I get a response back when I call the API. But I'll try to look at it again later today. Be right back. @Ferin Patel

Comment: It's like that I've made use of UseRef, it's set to useRef(False) at the top of the code, but it's like that with if(!ignore) it doesn't get any further than that.

Comment: I have solved it by saying that when it goes through and the data is successful, I pull it out and add some values and if they are assigned those values then I can use useRef which adds a message to the user. So Thanks for Help @ferin Patel.